# iTextSharp add subtable without external border

Tags: vb.net, itext

I'm trying to use ItextSharp to create pdf from my web app.
to create a Header section on every page of my pdf, I create a partial class where I override the `OnEndPage` method.
Everything works fine, with just one exception.
I designed my header as a table with 2 columns, in the first I put a logo, and in the second I want to show some text on multiple lines; so in the second cell I created a subtable with 1 column and several rows, but this subtable always shows the external black border which I'm not able to remove.
Here is the code:

```
    Public Overrides Sub OnEndPage(writer As PdfWriter, document As Document)
    Dim headerIMG As Image = Image.GetInstance(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(logoPath))
    Dim pageSize As Rectangle = document.PageSize
    Dim headerTbl As New PdfPTable(2)
    headerTbl.TotalWidth = 600 
    headerTbl.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER

    Dim cell As New PdfPCell(headerIMG)
    cell.Border = 0 
    cell.PaddingLeft = 10
    cell.PaddingBottom = 10
    headerTbl.AddCell(cell)

    Dim subTable = New PdfPTable(1)
    For Each s As String In HeaderText
        Dim myCell As New PdfPCell(New Paragraph(s))
        myCell.Border = 0
        subTable.AddCell(myCell)
    Next
    subTable.DefaultCell.BorderWidth = 0
    headerTbl.AddCell(subTable)

    headerTbl.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 0, pageSize.GetTop(5), writer.DirectContent)
End Sub
```

Anyone can help?
Thanks a lot

Comment: I replaced `OnStartPage` by `OnEndPage` because you should never add content in the `OnStartPage` method (as documented).

Comment: One suggestion, and question : can You avoid subtable? Instead subtable just add content in the right cell. `DIm ss As String = "": For Each s As String In HeaderText: ss+=s+vbCrLf:Next: cell=New PdfPCell(New Paragraph(ss)): cell.BorderWidth="0": headerTbl.AddCell(cell)` ...just store `ss` in right cell. If You must have subtable, then nothing. And, of course, that thing what Bruno wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things are wrong in your code. For instance: you create a new `headerIMG` object for each page. This means that the same image bytes will be added to the PDF over and over again. You should declare `headerIMG` *outside* the `OnStartPage` method.

Furthermore: you are defining a `BorderWidth` of 0. As defined in the PDF specification, a line width of 0 doesn't mean that there is no line. Please read ISO-32000-1, section 8.4.3.2 "Line Width":

> A line width of 0 shall denote the thinnest line that can be rendered at device resolution: 1 device pixel wide.

If you don't want a border, tell iText that you don't want a border:

```
Dim headerIMG As Image = Image.GetInstance(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(logoPath))

Public Overrides Sub OnStartPage(writer As PdfWriter, document As Document)
    Dim pageSize As Rectangle = document.PageSize
    Dim headerTbl As New PdfPTable(2)
    headerTbl.TotalWidth = 600 
    headerTbl.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER

    Dim cell As New PdfPCell(headerIMG)
    cell.Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER
    cell.PaddingLeft = 10
    cell.PaddingBottom = 10
    headerTbl.AddCell(cell)

    Dim subTable = New PdfPTable(1)
    For Each s As String In HeaderText
        Dim myCell As New PdfPCell(New Paragraph(s))
        myCell.Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER
        subTable.AddCell(myCell)
    Next
    subTable.DefaultCell.Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER
    headerTbl.AddCell(subTable)
    headerTbl.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 0, pageSize.GetTop(5), writer.DirectContent)
End Sub
```

Do you see what I changed?

Also, please read the comment provided by [nelek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3279496/nelek). Why do you need a sub table? You can easily define a rowspan for the cell containing the image.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! Using the constant PdfPCell.NoBorder it works the same as 0, since it is a constat value = 0. So I used the nelek method and now I'm getting what I was looking for. Thank you both very much for your help!!!

Comment: Also Thanks for advising me to create the logo object just once for all the pages